# Exclude current Angular Material Date Picker from Date Picker Filter function

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-material

I am facing the following scenario :

I have a form array that allows to dynamically add or remove Angular Material MatDateRangePicker objects. When a specific range is selected in a dateRangePicker, I want that range to be disabled in the other dateRangePickers of the form array.

I am using the dateFilterFn method to apply the filter.

My problem is that when a range is selected in a specific dateRangePicker, it disables that specific range in all the other dateRangePickers (which is the desired behaviour), but also disables that range in the current dateRangePicker. So when I re-open that picker in which we just applied the range, the entire range is disabled which isn't convenient if I want to re-apply a new range in this picker which includes dates of the previously selected range within that same dateRangePicker.

[image]

If someone can help me figure this out, I'd be very grateful.

I created a stackBlitz project that simulates this feature of the application that I am developing :
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-zjpbcw?file=src/app/app.component.ts